# Matching multiple values in a cell to another cell with multiple values

Tags: excel, vba

For a much more involved macro I am writing, I am trying to parse through a row of information. Two of the cells in that row may contain multiple values in them. If and when that is the case, I want to match them to their corresponding values.

For example: If one cell in the row had "1 2 3" written to it, and the other "10 5 15", I would want to match "1" with "10", "2" with "5", and "3" with "15". from what I've gathered, the Split() function is what I should be using, with the delimiter being the space, but I don't have much experience with VBA syntax and would greatly appreciate if someone could explain and/or show me how they'd use Split() in that context, or point me in the direction of a different solution to this problem.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Stack Overflow is more of a "show me your code and I'll help you debug it" site, not "how to write / use this code" site. Google is your best friend for figuring out how to do things. If you have some code, even if it is terrible and not working, put it up so others can point out what is wrong with it.

Comment: That's what I thought too.. Then when I put in my code last time, I was told "We aren't going to sift through your code to tell you whats wrong with it."... The community doesn't seem to be as consistent with the purpose of this site. I will add my code shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code to read values from excel cell and split them, here split is based on space so parameter for that is not provided, if there is another split parameter it will look like

```
Split(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1), ":")
```

sample code with split with spaces. compare the values later using any loop with iterator.

```
Dim Value1() As String
Dim Value2() As String
Function comparecells()

    Value1 = Split(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1))
    Debug.Print Value1(0)
    Debug.Print Value1(1)
    Debug.Print Value1(2)
    Value2 = Split(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2))
    Debug.Print Value2(0)
    Debug.Print Value2(1)
    Debug.Print Value2(2)    

End Function
```

Comment: when you say split is based on space so parameter for that is not provided, is that to say that space is the default parameter for the split() function?

Comment: Yes, if you don't give any split parameter it considers space as default one.